# How to change the overall font of WordPress site?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

I am using Duster as my theme. I want to change the default font. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be on wordpress site

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Easy Google Fonts Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-google-fonts/)

**Step 1** install plugin and then go to => setting => google fonts . Add a css selector like if you want to change the whole website font family change , then add a body css selector .

**step 2** Go to => Apperance => customize => Typography => Theme Typography => add a font family you want to use .

Answer (score 0):

...or, if you don't like plugins, simply do this and add stylesheet with it after all the other stylesheets in header:

```
body {
    font-family:Whatever, "Whatever In Space", sans-serif; /* Actual fonts of course chosen by you */
}
```

If this doesn't work and is overriden change to `font-family:Whatever, "Whatever In Space", sans-serif !important;`, but using `!important` is generally considered a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the font without using any plugin, you can follow the steps below:

1. For example if you want to change fonts to BYekan or any other fonts, you have to create a font folder in `wp-content->themes->my theme->font`.
2. Upload the fonts to this folder.
3. In beginning of the CSS file, add these lines:

   ```css
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'BYekan';
       src: url('font/WebYekan.eot');
       src: url('font/WebYekan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('font/WebYekan.woff') format('woff'),
            url('font/WebYekan.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('font/WebYekan.svg#WebYekan') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
   }
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'BKoodakBold';
       src: url('font/BKoodakBold.eot');
       src: url('font/BKoodakBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('font/BKoodakBold.ttf') format('truetype');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       -moz-font-feature-settings: "calt=0,liga=0";
   }
   ```
4. Change `font-family` to:

   ```css
   font-family:"BKoodakBold",BKoodak,byekan,Arial,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
   ```

   everywhere you want to change the font.